# Integration by parts on the Riemann sphere

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, riemann-surfaces

I have two ways of integrating the area of the $2$-sphere, reaching contradictory results. The first method is the usual one:

$A=\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}d\theta \,\,\,\sin\theta=4\pi $

Lets now use stereographic co-ordinates, projecting from the south pole, i.e. $z=e^{i\phi}\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$. Getting the Jacobian factors correct we find that our integral becomes:

$A=4\int d^2z \frac{1}{(1+|z|^2)^2}$

Now I can write the integrand as double derivative:

$\partial_{z}\partial_{\bar{z}}\ln(1+|z|^2)=\partial_z\frac{z}{1+|z|^2}=\frac{1}{1+|z|^2}-\frac{|z|^2}{(1+|z|^2)^2}=\frac{1}{(1+|z|^2)^2}$

So I can write the integral as:

$A=\int d^2z \partial_z\partial_{\bar{z}}\ln(1+|z|^2)$

Now using integration by parts/Stokes theorem, the integral just evaluates to its value at the boundary of the integration manifold. Because we are on the $2$-sphere/Riemann sphere and not just the complex plane, the manifold over which we are integrating does not have a boundary and hence the integral evaluates to zero:

$A=0$

Which is a contradiction. Where is the incorrect logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that $z$ takes values on $\mathbb{C}$, and not on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$.

The stereographic projection relates the sphere to the plane plus infinity. The area of the sphere is
$$ A = \int\limits_{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1} \, 1 \; . $$
This integral is the same if you integrate over the whole sphere minus one point (set of measure zero). This area is equal to the area of the sphere without the North pole
$$ A = \int\limits_{\mathbb{S}^2-\mathrm{N}} \, 1 \ $$
and the stereographic projection gives a map to the complex plane. With the usual parameterization
$$  A = 4\int\limits_{\mathbb{C}} d^2z \, \partial_{z}\partial_{\bar{z}} \, \ln (1+\vert z \vert^2)  $$
and $d^2z := d\mathrm{Re}z  \wedge d\mathrm{Im}{z} = \frac{1}{2i} \, d\bar{z} \wedge dz  \, $.

---

#### Explicitly calculating the integral

Indeed, the integral is not hard to calculate. Integrate over a disc of radius $R$ and take the limit $R\to \infty$,
$$ A=  \frac{4}{2i} \lim_{R\to \infty}\;\int\limits_{\vert z \vert < R} d\bar{z} \wedge dz\, \partial_{z}\partial_{\bar{z}} \, \ln (1+\vert z \vert^2) $$
Appling Stokes theorem
\begin{align} A &= \frac{4}{2i} \lim_{R\to \infty}\;\int\limits_{\vert z \vert = R} d\bar{z} \, \partial_{\bar{z}} \, \ln (1+\vert z \vert^2) = \frac{4}{2i} \lim_{R\to \infty}\;\int\limits_{\vert z \vert = R} d\bar{z} \, \frac{z}{1+\vert z \vert^2} \; \\
&= \frac{4}{2i} \lim_{R\to \infty}\;\int\limits_{\vert z \vert = R} \frac{d\bar{z}}{\bar{z}} \, \frac{\vert z \vert^2 }{1+\vert z \vert^2} = \frac{4}{2i}  \lim_{R\to \infty} \, 2 \pi i \; \frac{R^2}{1+R^2} \\ 
&= 4 \pi \; . \end{align}

Comment: Do you think another solution would be to use two co-ordinate systems, namely projecting from the south pole for $\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and projecting from the north pole for $\theta>\frac{\pi}{2}$ so that the expression $\ln(1+|z|^2)$ is finite in each domain of the relevant coordinate system?

Comment: I edited my answer for clarifying that the area of the sphere does not depend on the North pole. The question is that the original integral is over the sphere, but after that, you make the projection to the complex plane and the integral is fine.

Comment: Note that the function that matters in the integral over the complex plane is the derivative of $\ln(1+\vert z \vert^2)$, that is $z/(1+\vert z \vert^2)$. This function goes to zero at infinity.

Comment: Why in this setting can we not use the concept of "a boundary of a boundary is zero"? i.e. Take the circle of radius $\epsilon$ at the north pole to be the boundary of our integration region (and we take $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ at the end of the calculation). Because naively, it appears that the $\partial_z\partial_{\bar{z}}$ should take me to boundary of the boundary of some integration domain.

Comment: Yes, it is this that is happening, but the boundary is the circle of radius $R$ as $R\to \infty$. This circle is precisely the identification of your " the circle of radius $\epslion$ at the north pole" after the stereographic projection (from the sphere to the complex plane).

Comment: I get that a single $\partial_z$ is taking us to this $\epsilon$ boundary at the north pole. I was asking why we cannot utilize the second partial derivative. i.e. You have the expression $\int_{|z|=R} d\bar{z}\partial_{\bar{z}}\ln(1+|z|^2)$ so why can we not use Stokes theorem again at this step? I think the answer is because you have to at this point adapt your coordinate system to the $|z|=R$ constraint, hence we use a $\phi$ cordinate to keep us on the constraint, but the integrand is not of the form $\partial_{\phi}f(\phi)$ in that case so we cannot use Stokes a second time.

Comment: Oh, now I understand your question. Good point, the integral of an exact form over a closed chain is zero. However, here you can't use Stokes because it is not a exact form $d\bar{z} \partial_{\bar{z}} \ln(1+\vert z \vert^2) \neq dg$. We would need to add another term, e.g. $dz \partial_{z} \ln(1+\vert z \vert^2) $ for we be able to use Stoke's theorem again.